# Assembly Cannot be cast

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, assemblies

Here is my code that loads a dll file and writes info about the file in xml:

```
MyOptions ass = MyOptionsList[MyOptionsList.Count - 1];
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(ass.GetType(),
    new Type[] { typeof(MyOptions) });
serializer.Serialize(sw, ass);
//more code writing in an xml file
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;

Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    return Assembly.LoadFrom(correctPath + ".dll");
}
```

The problem happens in the line `serializer.Serialize(sw, ass);`. The inner exception says that I can't cast from one dll to another. Both dll files have the same name. One is on the `correctPath`, and the second is on some other path. How to resolve this?

MyOptions is a class library project from which the dll I am loading is extending.

Comment: What is your code trying to achieve?

Comment: @GregC Load a dll file and write info about that in xml.

Comment: @GregC MyOptions is a class library project from which the dll I am loading is extending.

Comment: This section of code doesn't explain how you got the dll into ass.

Comment: What is the exact exception message and the stack trace?

Comment: @Srcee you haven't explained what MyOptions actually is. It obviously is some sort of class, but that's all I can figure. Also, there would be no exception error message that says you can't cast from one DLL to another because DLLs aren't things that can be cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried the below with no problems, I think your problem must lie elsewhere.

```
public class MyOptions
{
  public int n;
}

static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
  return Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\windwos\test.dll");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  MyOptions ass = new MyOptions();
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(ass.GetType(), new Type[] { typeof(MyOptions) });
  serializer.Serialize(sw, ass);
  //more code writing in an xml file
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
}
```

Note that the event code isn't called.